# Why are the elif statements not working?

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to make a calculator but for some reason when it comes to picking an operation it will only do add the elif statements do not execute even if i input the right command for it

```
print("welcome to the simple calculator  please type in a number")
#user enters 1st number
Num1=int(input("type a number between 0-9"))
#user enters 2nd number
Num2=int(input("please type in your second number"))    
#user enters the operation that is used

Ope=input("would you like to divde,add,subtract or times")
#adds the numbers
if Ope=="add"or"Add":
    print(Num1+Num2)
#subtracts the numbers

elif Ope=="subtract" or "Subtract":
    print(Num1-Num2)

elif Ope=="times" or "Times":
    print(Num1*Num2)

elif Ope=="divide" or "Divide":
    print(Num1/Num2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Not that you need to do that, just `.lower()` the input.

Comment: They are working. You're making up your own syntax and somehow expecting python to know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Code `Ope=="add"or"Add"` is evaluated in the order defined by [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence): first `==`, then `or`.

So, for any `Ope` other than "add", it evaluates to:

`(Ope == "add") or "Add"` => `False or "Add"` => `"Add"`

and for `Ope` equal to "add", it evaluates to:

`(Ope == "add") or "Add"` => `True or "Add"` => `True`

Therefore, the value is either `"Add"` or `True`, and both of them are *true* (see [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) and the first `if` will always be satisfied.

(see also [how `or` works](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#or))

---

### Solution

```
if Ope.lower() == "add":
    ...
elif Ope.lower() == "subtract":
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two weird things you are doing here that will cause you problems:

1. When comparing a single variable against multiple values, there are many ways to do it, but to keep things simple, you should change:

   ```
   if Ope=="add"or"Add":
   ```

   to

   ```
   if Ope == "add" or Ope == "Add":
   ```

   This is **not** the best way to compare against multiple values, but it is a simple way to do what you are *trying* to do. However, you will achieve unexpected results with the way you have it now. `Ope == "add" or "Add"` will always be `True` because what this actually does is checks the truth value of `Ope == "add"` and of `"Add"` and returns the first one that evaluates to `True`, or the second one if neither is `True`. In this case `bool("Add")` will always be `True`, so you will always get the `if` block. If that doesn't make sense to you, don't worry; it really is confusing in my opinion. It is something that you will eventual just start to get if you work with Python long enough.
2. You are checking for case, when you could just `.lower()` the value of `Ope` and test against the lowercase version:

   ```
   Ope = input("would you like to divide,add,subtract or times").lower()
   if Ope=="add":  # and do the same for the elif statements
   ...
   ```